# how to store current page data using cookie and display it in next page(result.jsp) when submit

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body bgcolor="pink">     
<form name="sorter" action="result.jsp" method="post">
    <div  align="right">
        <textarea style="overflow:auto;resize:none" id="sorter2" name="sorter2"  rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="100" wrap="hard"></textarea><br>     
        <input type="button" value="Numbers in Asc" onClick="SortNumbers()">           
    </div> 
    <div  align="center">
        <textarea style="overflow:auto;resize:none" id="sorter3" name="sorter3" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="100" wrap="hard"></textarea><br>
        <input type="button" value="words in Asc" onClick="SortWords()">                  
    </div>        
    <p align="center">
        <input type="Submit" value="View">               
    </p>
</form>
```

For this correspondig html page i have javascript as follows it is working properly but my question is when i click on view button it goes to next page(result.jsp) how can i pass current page data using cookies and how to display in result.jsp page,thanks in advance

javascript is:

```
function SortNumbers(){
var arr=document.getElementById("sorter2").value.split(",");  
arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return a-b
});    
document.getElementById("sorter2").value=arr;  
alert("The least value is:"+arr[0])
alert("Highest value is:"+arr[arr.length-1])
```

}

```
function SortWords() {
var inputvalues = document.getElementById("sorter3").value.split(" ");   
inputvalues.sort(function (x, y) {
    return x.length > y.length;
});
//document.getElementById("sorter3").value = inputvalues;
alert("smallest word is: " + inputvalues[0])
alert("longest word is: " + inputvalues[inputvalues.length - 1]);
document.getElementById("sorter3").value = inputvalues.join(' ');
```

}

Comment: Which data do you want to send?

Comment: whatever i entered in text areas for sortnumbers and sortwords that data i want to display in next page,could u plz give me the logic

Comment: Why would you want to use cookies for that, when you are already using a form to transfer data? Append whatever extra data you have to the form, so that on the next page you can simply read it together with the rest of the values.